# Shared Form Saving Issues

Tags: error, settings, saving

I am trying to create my own settings form (EE5) using the documentation, but when i am using the function settings_form() & save_settings() and calling the "return ee('View')->make('my_extension:index')->render($vars);" it will not save. It displays correctly and submits the form but doesn't save. When I run the settings() function it works fine, but I need to create some custom areas. Anyone experiencing similar issues with it not saving.

Comment: When using custom settings methods, you need to perform the save routine yourself within `save_settings()`. Are you manually saving your extension settings in that method?

Comment: I am not saving them manually. I was under the impression that when the save_settings() method is called it will submit the form data automatically to the /save. I watched the data and both save_settings() and settings() are submitting the same parameters but one is saving and the other isn't. How do I save the settings manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `save_settings()` method doesn't do anything with your settings data simply by existing - you need to process the submission yourself. From [the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extensions.html#save-settings):

> Use it to process the data sent and put it into the `exp_extensions` database table. Remember that the data put into the database is a serialized array, so handle it appropriately.

The easiest way to do this is using the existing Extension model, which abstracts a lot of that work for you:

```
$model = ee('Model')->get('Extension')
    ->filter('class', ucfirst(get_class($this)))
    ->first();

$my_settings = array(
    'foo' => ee('Request')->post('foo'),
    'bar' => ee('Request')->post('bar')
);

$model->settings = $my_settings;
$model->save();
```

(Since the `settings` property of the `Extension` model is set to be serialized data, you only have to assign an array to it - the serialization will happen in the model.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Derek you answer was spot on!